# Leaflet - how to rotate latlong 90degrees?

Tags: leaflet

Wrong
[image]

Right
[image]

Ive got a CRS.simple map made from x y coordinates. When inserted with markers, they go as the 1st image shows, but they should go as they are in the 2nd image. How do i get that rotation to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRS.Simple coords are in the format `[y,x]`

You can switch them with following:

```
var yx = L.latLng;

var xy = function(x, y) {
    if (L.Util.isArray(x)) {    // When doing xy([x, y]);
        return yx(x[1], x[0]);
    }
    return yx(y, x);  // When doing xy(x, y);
};
```

https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html#this-is-not-the-latlng-youre-looking-for

**Update**

Mirror the coords with adding a minus:

```
var yx = L.latLng;

var xy = function(x, y) {
    if (L.Util.isArray(x)) {    // When doing xy([x, y]);
        return yx(-x[1], -x[0]);
    }
    return yx(-y, -x);  // When doing xy(x, y);
};
```

Comment: With that i get the right version, but mirrored. That blue thingy is on the right and the green on the left. But in their correct places if i just get it mirrored. Is there a trick to do that?

Comment: Ok, that mirrored the whole map. I guess i meant to say that it is mirrored left <-> right. Not all the way. I guess i can solve this myself,  take the minus off the other axis?

Comment: Yes I think this should make it work. Can you please accept / upvote the answer